# How to specify return type format for google fonts?

Tags: css, google-fonts

I am trying to load fonts from google fonts with the following snippet

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
```

It loads following css

```
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat Italic'), local('Montserrat-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/-iqwlckIhsmvkx0N6rwPmv8zf_FOSsgRmwsS7Aa9k2w.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat Italic'), local('Montserrat-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/-iqwlckIhsmvkx0N6rwPmj0LW-43aMEzIO6XUTLjad8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
```

The problem is it returns **woff2** font format. Is there any way to load **woff** or **ttf** formats instead of **woff2**? Because the woff2 is not rendering properly in older browsers.

Comment: You can just download the font files and call them from a local folder in your project. You can download them as ttf or woff files.

Comment: @DragomirKolev I have more than 100 fonts. Local doesn't sounds good. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Fonts will do browser sniffing and attempt to [serve up only the relevant font formats](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/technical_considerations#what_is_the_google_fonts_api_serving).

This means that the loaded CSS will be **different** depending on the browser that loads it.

They [do support](https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#which_browsers_are_supported) older browsers. In particular:

> - Google Chrome: version 4.249.4+
> - Mozilla Firefox: version: 3.5+
> - Apple Safari: version 3.1+
> - Opera: version 10.5+
> - Microsoft Internet Explorer: version 6+

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, google pre-determines which file types are needed and only serves those. They do so primarily via the requestor's `User-Agent` header.

Luckily, this header can be emulated in the dev tools so in case you need the `.ttf` resources, you can use a `Blackberry` or other similar, older device to obtain the *actual* font URLs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As google doesn't help us to directly download fonts, I didn't find a way to do this, but you can check this github repo to help you :

https://github.com/google/fonts/

Answer (score -1):

If you are resigned to controlling specifically what format is to be used, one approach is to simply use your own stylesheet with the `src` changed out and/or sourcing the style declarations from the desired target.